# Azure Load Balanced Application error on one server

Tags: azure, asp.net

I have a application that is load balanced in azure but I have one server that is not working correctly. How can I hit that specific server with my browser to tell what is going on ? Any tricks people know of ?

Comment: What is your specific error? and what is the meaning of "one server that is not working correctly. ", can you describe it? I suppose you have an Azure load balancer with two VMs which can be hosted an application? right?

Comment: Yes 2 vms behind a load balancer 1 server is giving yellow screen of death not sure which one and would like to be able to uniquely hit each

Comment: Where do you see this error? Could you show some screenshots?

Comment: Can you check the boot screenshots status for your backend VMs from virtual machine---boot diagnostics on the portal?

Comment: really my question is actually not about the actual error. I am wanting to know how to get to the actual server individually in the cluster

Comment: well, could you describe more details about your current environment,  Which cluster? Kubernetes? or others?

Comment: Are you using a basic load balancer or standard load balancer? with public IP or private IP address? You can directly RDP or SSH to the specific server if there are public IPs of an individual server.

Comment: The basic load balancer in asure as far as I know. It has a public IP with the load balancer and then two private ips for internal. I can remote desktop into the servers fine but I want to hit that specific website there are multiple websites on the box

Comment: Really not sure your question. Perhaps,  after you RDP to each server, you can check if the website is working on the individual server with your browser or refer to [this](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-check-if-website-is-working-worldwide#gref).